KQL query returns available memory but not Total Memory
When i run this KQL query it does not return total memory of a VM just the available memory.
I am trying to calculate the % available memory but i cant without the total memory on the VM.
What am i doing wrong? I have validated the available memory which appears to be accurate.


You can use this Query to fetch the total memory and percentage of available memory..

Thanks but your query is looking at disk space (Usage) and not Memory.

InsightsMetrics
| where Origin == "vm.azm.ms" and Namespace == "LogicalDisk" and Name == "FreeSpaceMB"
| extend Disk = tostring(todynamic(Tags)["vm.azm.ms/mountId"]),
Disk_Size_GB = todouble(todynamic(Tags)["vm.azm.ms/diskSizeMB"]) / 1024,
Disk_Free_Space_GB = todouble(Val) / (1024 * 1024)
| summarize avg(Disk_Free_Space_GB) as Avg_Free_Space_GB by Computer, Disk, Disk_Size_GB, _ResourceId
| extend Percent_Free_Space = (Avg_Free_Space_GB / Disk_Size_GB) * 100
| project Computer, Disk, Disk_Size_GB, Avg_Free_Space_GB, Percent_Free_Space
Check this

no not correct either.


KQL query returns available memory but not Total Memory

You can use below KQL query to fetch the VM Total memory, free memory and percentage of free memory
InsightsMetrics
| where Origin == "vm.azm.ms" and Namespace == "Memory"
| extend TotalMemoryGB=(todynamic(Tags)["vm.azm.ms/memorySizeMB"])/(1000)
| summarize AailableMemoryGB = avg(Val)/(1000) by Computer, TotalMemoryGB, _ResourceId
| extend Availabile_Memory_Percentage=(AailableMemoryGB/TotalMemoryGB)*100
| project Computer, TotalMemoryGB, AailableMemoryGB,Availabile_Memory_Percentage

Output:

Reference: KQL Query Free Disk Space

slight correction (1024 in place of 1000)
InsightsMetrics
| where Origin == "vm.azm.ms" and Namespace == "Memory"
| extend TotalMemoryGB=(todynamic(Tags)["vm.azm.ms/memorySizeMB"])/(1024)
| summarize AvailableMemoryGB = avg(Val)/(1024) by Computer, TotalMemoryGB, _ResourceId
| extend Availabile_Memory_Percentage=(AvailableMemoryGB/TotalMemoryGB)*100
| project Computer, TotalMemoryGB, AvailableMemoryGB,Availabile_Memory_Percentage
